# Encrypting user passwords, save secret key to file

Tags: encryption, rust, passwords

I'm trying to make secure keeping users passwords in database. After quick research I decided use ed25519_dalek library.

Important notice:
I plan use this encryption in actix website.

For now steps are simple:

1. save password in variable,
2. generate keys,
3. save secret and public passwords in file(for now),
4. encrypt password,
5. save password to database(skipping for now),

I'm stack in third step: saving keys to file.
To be honest I can write passwords to file, but can't read it.

My code below:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::{BufRead, Write};
use rand::rngs::OsRng;
use ed25519_dalek::{Keypair, PublicKey, Signature, Signer, Verifier};
use ed25519_dalek::{PUBLIC_KEY_LENGTH, SECRET_KEY_LENGTH, KEYPAIR_LENGTH, SIGNATURE_LENGTH};


let mut csprng = OsRng{};
let keypair: Keypair = Keypair::generate(&mut csprng);


let password: &[u8] = b"testing_password123!@#$%";

let signature: Signature = keypair.sign(password);


assert!(keypair.verify(&password, &signature).is_ok());
```

For this moment my code works well. I'm getting signature and looks like values password and signature are the same.

I'm trying to deserialize keys:

```
let public_key_bytes: [u8; PUBLIC_KEY_LENGTH] = keypair.public.to_bytes();
let secret_key_bytes: [u8; SECRET_KEY_LENGTH] = keypair.secret.to_bytes();
let keypair_bytes:    [u8; KEYPAIR_LENGTH]    = keypair.to_bytes();
let signature_bytes:  [u8; SIGNATURE_LENGTH]  = signature.to_bytes();
```

After this, I want to save secret key and public key to different files. But for simplify we want to save only secret key.

My steps below:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;


let filename = "keys.txt";
let path = Path::new(filename);
let display = path.display();

let mut file = match File::create(&path) {
    Err(why) => panic!("Couldn't create {}: {}", display, why),
    Ok(file) => file,
};

match file.write_all(&secret_key_bytes) {
    Err(why) => panic!("couldn't write to {}: {}", display, why),
    Ok(_) => println!("successfully wrote to {}", display),
};
```

In this step I can write bytes to a file. But... The key has type [u8;32]. Using cat command showing strange things(I understand why).

But I can't read this file. Bytes can't be read like this.

After this entry is time for my question:
How can I change type of secret key [u8;32] to String or str?

My idea is:
Change datatype to String or str and then save to file.

Or maybe I do something wrong or simply is it better way to do this?

I need little push in right way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unsafe to encrypt and store passwords in a database. Moreover you are planning to store both public and private keys in files. The program requires it to be kept in reach for authenticating, so it won't be hard for someone to find the files with public and private keys. Anyone who have access to those files can access users' passwords including you.

The workaround is to generate a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) from the password and store it in the database. Hashing is a one way process of generating a string from an input string such that the inverse operation is impossible. So,the hash of the user input and the hash in the database is matched to authorize the user. There are a bunch of hashing functions available in RUST including the [SHA-2 family hashing functions](https://docs.rs/sha2/latest/sha2/).

It is still insecure if you are just hashing the passwords and saving them in the database since the hashes of most common passwords and almost all possible words are already available in datasets named hash dictionaries and by using that, anyone who have access to your database can find the password. This technique is called [dictionary attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack). To prevent it, you can make the input string larger by concatenating with some random characters ([salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))) with the user input and
store the hash and the salt in the database.

Comment: A hash function specifically designed for passwords should be used. Argon2 is the modern standard, but older techniques like scrpyt, bcrypt, or even pbkdf2 are vastly superior to a single application of any of the SHA-2 hash functions.

Comment: Thanks! Great tips.
So I'll try to use Argon2 hash. For now I didn't know this.

Salt looks interesting too, I need to get more knowledge about it.

Comment: Rust implementation of Argon2 already contains Salt. Here is link [argon2](https://docs.rs/argon2/latest/argon2/)